# OAuth library for ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am working on ReactJS SPA. I am trying to find the library which I can use for OAuth2 from my React SPA to get the authorization code.
I tried using auth0 libraries but auth0 libraries redirect to /authorize endpoint only and there is no way to configure it.
Our company's authentication server's authorization endpoint is /as/authorization.
Can someone please help which React library can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that can be easily done with [Pizzly](https://github.com/Bearer/Pizzly/tree/master/src/clients/javascript), an open-source OAuth Integrations manager.

Here's an example of how to use Pizzly to retrieve an `accessToken`:

```js
const App = () => {

  // Initialize Pizzly
  const pizzly = new Pizzly({ host: PIZZLY_HOSTNAME, publishableKey: PIZZLY_PUBLISHABLE_KEY })

  // Use the GitHub API
  const github = pizzly.integration('github')

  // The connect method lets us authenticate a user
  // to our GitHub OAuth application
  const connect = () => {
    github
      .connect()
      .then(({ authId, payload }) => {
        console.log(authId, payload.accessToken)
      })
      .catch(console.error)
  }

  // ...
};

export default App;
```

I've recently written a tutorial on [how to use Pizzly + React](https://dev.to/frenchcooc/how-to-make-api-calls-in-react-g1e).

Answer (score 2):

The most mainstream and mature library is [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). Here are a couple of code samples of mine that use it:

- [Basic Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1)
- [React Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final)

The GitHub repos link to some blog posts that might be useful also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Pathfix, we have a login extension that connects to multiple providers.

Can you elaborate your OAuth use case. I am assuming since you mentioned Auth0 you are trying to use it as a login provider?

Disclaimer: I work with them

Comment: We have our own authentication server. I tried to use auth0 react libraries to connect with our authentication server but I couldn't as we don't have /authorize end point for our authentication service

Comment: The endpoint at /as/authorization should be fine. The way libraries work is to start with the metadata endpoint and look up other endpoints from there. Maybe have a look at my [Initial Messages Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) and see if you can find the endpoint from step 3.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using hello.js in our app.

We had to customize it but it worked.